# Can I ask here which is the best SE site to ask a particular question on?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Well, this might seem like a meta [inception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception). :)

I have a question regarding an application that I have been using. I can't ask that question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) because it is not on programming. I am not sure if I can ask that on [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Is it okay to share that question here on [SE Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) to understand which is the best SE site to ask it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag wiki says:

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites,
>   you don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange
>   Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like
>   to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

If you have looked through https://stackexchange.com/sites and still don't know which site to try asking your question on then it seems fine for your to provide details about it and ask for a site recommendation here.

However, I think you should also look through [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598)